# How to create a list with values ​from state?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

In the application, when I click on the button, I write the name of the group in the field and add it to the database. The name of the group is also displayed on the screen. My problem is that every time I create a new group, it is overwritten on the screen.
And I need to display the names of the groups on the screen as a list and so that it is added and not overwritten. But the implementation is such that in my state there is not a list and it is impossible to display the names of groups using map. How can I display the titles as a list so they don't get overwritten?

```js
@immutable
abstract class NewGroupState {
  const NewGroupState();
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
class NewGroupInitial extends NewGroupState {
  const NewGroupInitial();
}
class AddGroupState extends NewGroupState {
  const AddGroupState(this.group);
  final Group group;
}
```

```js
body: BlocBuilder<NewGroupBloc, NewGroupState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(state is AddGroupState ? state.group.groupName : ''),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: You're misleading the concept of **state** and **event**. Events are to change the state. But states, they represent the current variables of your system, in this case your UI through BLoC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question, is this what you're trying to do?
If not, can you rewrite your question?

```dart
class AddGroupState extends NewGroupState {
  const AddGroupState(this.currentGroup, this.previousGroups);
  final Group currentCroup;
  final List<Group> previousGroups;
}
```

```dart
class NewGroupBloc extends Bloc<NewGroupState> {
    Future<void> addGroupToDB() async {
        final newGroup = Group();
        try {
            // add group to DB
            await _groupRepository.add(newGroup);
            final updatedGroups = [...state.previousGroups, newGroup];
            emit(NewGroupState(newGroup, updatedGroups));
        } on DBError catch (e) {
            emit(NewGroupErrorState());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: this is a **BAD** answer but author asked how it could be done.

```dart
class NewGroupBloc extends Bloc<NewGroupState> {
    late Future<void> Function(Group group) onAddGroup;

    Future<void> addGroupToDB() async {
        final newGroup = Group();
        try {
            await _groupRepository.add(newGroup);
            await onAddGroup(newGroup);
            emit(NewGroupState(newGroup));
        } on DBError catch (e) {
            emit(NewGroupErrorState());
        }
    }
}
```

```dart
class _GroupPageState extends State<GroupPage> {
    var groups = <Group>[];
    NewGroupBloc bloc = // don't know how it was initialized

    @override
    void initState() {
        bloc.onAddGroup = (newGroup) {
            setState(() {
                groups = [...groups, newGroup];
            });
        }
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // The same as you already have, but using groups declared in the Widget instead of BLoC's state.
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't change in state group to List. How it is possible to display titles in the form of the list with such implementation? Because, as shown in the example, now it overwrites the titles

Comment: You're asking a design question, you'll have to compromise something to achieve what you want. If you can't change Group to List<Group>, than can you add another attribute to the state which is a List<Group> ?

Comment: The state class should represent the state of the UI. Anything that is shown in the screen should be in the state. If you can't put it in the NewGroupState, you can put it a parent state, but "can't change the state" seems like a weird reason to do that. You'd usually lift state up to share this data with other screens.

Comment: Can I create an empty list on the page and add group names to it and list them out?

Comment: You mean, adding a List in the StatefulWidget? You could? Would it work? Yes. Is it good? No, it's not, because this is not [ephemeral state](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app) and you're using BLoC to hold the app state, so you should put it in the BLoC state.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. But can you suggest how to do this?

Comment: It is what I suggested in the answer, but you said you can't change the AddGroupState class.

Comment: I changed the example above a bit, would you check if you can do that?

Comment: I'm talking about the option where you can create an empty List in the widget. I don't understand how it can be done

Comment: I added another example. Is this an college assignment or something like that? If it is so, this answer using setState and a List inside the Widget is clearly not what you're meant to do.